# pylint: Using possibly undefined loop variable 'n'

Tags: python, enumerate

Pylint says

```
W:  6: Using possibly undefined loop variable 'n'
```

... with this code:

```py
iterator = (i*i for i in range(100) if i % 3 == 0)

for n, i in enumerate(iterator):
    do_something(i)

print n
```

because if the iterator is empty (for example `[]`) `n` is undefined, ok. But I like this trick. How to use it in a safe way?

I think that using `len(list(iterator))` is not the best choice because you have to do two loops. I think that using a counter and incrementing it is not very pythonic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you considered merely initializing `n` to `None` before running the loop?

Comment: emm... yes, it was very simple

Answer (score 5):

Define a default value for `n` before the `for` statement:

```
iterator = (i*i for i in range(100) if i % 3 == 0)

n=None
for n, i in enumerate(iterator):
    do_something(i)

print n
```